# Why doesn't var_dump work with DOMDocument objects, while print($dom->saveHTML()) does?

Tags: php, domdocument

Why doesn't `var_dump` work with [DOMDocument](https://php.net/domdocument) objects, while `print($dom->saveHTML())` produces output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** As of PHP 5.4.1 you can finally `var_dump` DOM objects. See https://gist.github.com/2499678

---

It's a bug:

- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48527

Comment: @akond like I said in my answer (before the edit), I am bad at reading C Code, but you are probably right with the explanation. Removed my guess about Traversable. It's still a bug though.

Answer (score 6):

It has nothing to do with any interfaces and in fact is very simple.
var_dump shows only those class properties that **have been declared** by their developers by calling such C-functions as

```
ZEND_API int zend_declare_property(...)
ZEND_API int zend_declare_property_null(...)
ZEND_API int zend_declare_property_bool(...)
ZEND_API int zend_declare_property_long(...)
ZEND_API int zend_declare_property_double(...)
ZEND_API int zend_declare_property_string(...)
ZEND_API int zend_declare_property_stringl(...)
```

For instance, the properties of the class Exception are declared in the file Zend/zend_exceptions.c like this

```
   zend_declare_property_string(default_exception_ce, "message", sizeof("message")-1, "", ZEND_ACC_PROTECTED TSRMLS_CC);
   zend_declare_property_string(default_exception_ce, "string", sizeof("string")-1, "", ZEND_ACC_PRIVATE TSRMLS_CC);
   zend_declare_property_long(default_exception_ce, "code", sizeof("code")-1, 0, ZEND_ACC_PROTECTED TSRMLS_CC);
   zend_declare_property_null(default_exception_ce, "file", sizeof("file")-1, ZEND_ACC_PROTECTED TSRMLS_CC);
   zend_declare_property_null(default_exception_ce, "line", sizeof("line")-1, ZEND_ACC_PROTECTED TSRMLS_CC);
   zend_declare_property_null(default_exception_ce, "trace", sizeof("trace")-1, ZEND_ACC_PRIVATE TSRMLS_CC);
   zend_declare_property_null(default_exception_ce, "previous", sizeof("previous")-1, ZEND_ACC_PRIVATE TSRMLS_CC);
```

All these functions then call

```
ZEND_API int zend_declare_property_ex(zend_class_entry *ce, const char *name, ...
```

which updates the property list. Then comes the `var_dump` in `ext/standard/var.c` and looks them up by calling `php_object_property_dump` which enumerates them through the same property list. You see the **intentionally exposed** inner structure.

The developers of the DOM extension just **have chosen not to expose** the structure of their classes. They simply do not call those sort of functions. That is why you see nothing.

```
object(DOMDocument)#1 (0) {
}
```

If you look into `ext/dom/php_dom.c` you find a property declaration once. And it's for the DomException class. It redefines the property `code`.

```
zend_declare_property_long(dom_domexception_class_entry, "code", ...
```

If the Exception dump looks like

```
var_dump (new Exception ('test', 102));

object(Exception)#1 (7) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["string":"Exception":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["code":protected]=>
  int(102)
  ["file":protected]=>
  string(37) "/usr/local/www/apache22/data/dump.php"
  ["line":protected]=>
  int(3)
  ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["previous":"Exception":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

The DOMException dump is a little bit different.

```
 var_dump (new DOMException ());

object(DOMException)#2 (7) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["string":"Exception":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file":protected]=>
  string(37) "/usr/local/www/apache22/data/dump.php"
  ["line":protected]=>
  int(9)
  ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["previous":"Exception":private]=>
  NULL
  ["code"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

See how the code property moved to the end? It's because of redeclaration.

Comment: And how does this help?

Comment: @Juergen The question asked was "why does it behave this way?" not "how do I do X?" So this answers the question by explaining exactly why it behaves that way. There are many related "how do I ..." questions that could be asked, and they would have their own answers.