# XMLReader object is empty

Tags: php, xml

I am using XMLReader to read an XML file

Following is the code from XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk104">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
      <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
      Ascendant.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk105">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
      <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
      battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
      Oberon's Legacy.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk106">
      <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
      <title>Lover Birds</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
      <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
      conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk107">
      <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
      <title>Splish Splash</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
      thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk108">
      <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
      <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk109">
      <author>Kress, Peter</author>
      <title>Paradox Lost</title>
      <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
      <price>6.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
      Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
      of being quantum.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk110">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
      detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk111">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
      <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
      detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
      SAX and more.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk112">
      <author>Galos, Mike</author>
      <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>49.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Now, when I read from XML using following PHP Code:

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('/var/www/myhost/htdocs/books.xml');

while ($reader->read()) {
    print_r($reader);
}
```

Output comes like:

```
XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( )
XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( )
XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( )
XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( )
XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( ) XMLReader Object ( )
```

My Question is,

1. Why Object is empty?
2. How can I access data?

Comment: As for 1, see [Why `var_dump` cant print `DomDocument` object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776093/why-var-dump-cant-print-domdocument-object-only-with-printdom-savehtml-its/4776430). Same reason. It just doesnt expose it's internals.

Comment: @Gordon: I didn't get you. Can you please explain me.

Comment: No. Read the answers to the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php), you can

- access the value doing : $reader->value;
- access an attribute with $reader->getAttribute('attributename');
- check if the current node got attributes with $reader->hasAttributes; (which is a boolean)

etc...

consider $reader as a cursor in your xml.