# Why am I not getting back any images here?

Tags: php, domdocument

```
$url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp';
$html = @file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xml = @simplexml_import_dom($doc);
$images = $xml->xpath('//img');

var_dump($images);
die();
```

Output is:

```
array(0) { }
```

However, in the page source I see this:

```
<img border="0" width="336" height="69" src="/images/w3schoolslogo.gif" alt="W3Schools.com" style="margin-top:5px;" />
```

**Edit:** It appears `$html`'s contents stop at the `<body>` tag for this page. Any idea why?

Comment: What happens, if you remove the `@` in front of `file_get_contents()`? (actually, if you remove any `@` in that code)

Comment: Yes, I'd remove those `@` signs. Hopefully, you'll see some errors.

Comment: Perhaps the page is looking for some specific headers to be set in the request to prevent bots from grabbing the content. Try using `curl` instead and set the same headers as your browser. Use fiddler2 on Windows to see the browsers headers and something like Paros on Linux.

Comment: var_dump is not going to show you any information about DOM* objects because of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776093/why-var-dump-cant-print-domdocument-object-only-with-printdom-savehtml-its/4776208#4776208

Comment: Is this `<img border="0" width="336" height="69" src="/images/w3schoolslogo.gif" alt="W3Schools.com" style="margin-top:5px;" />`  the value of `array(0){}`, if that is the case, image would not display... try dumping `var_dump($images[0])`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> It appears $html's contents stop at the  tag for this page. Any idea why?

Yes, you must provide this page with a valid user agent.

```
$url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
curl_exec($ch);
```

outputs everything to the ending `</html>` including your requested `<img border="0" width="336" height="69" src="/images/w3schoolslogo.gif" alt="W3Schools.com" style="margin-top:5px;" />`

When a simple wget or curl without the user agent returns only up to the `<body>` tag.

```
$url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($ch);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
$images = $xml->xpath('//img');

var_dump($images);
die();
```

**EDIT:** *My first post stated that there was still an issue with xpath... I was just not doing my due diligence and the updated code above works great. I forgot to force curl to output to a string rather then print to the screen(as it does by default).*

Answer (score 0):

Why bring simplexml into the mix? You're already loading the HTML from [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/) into the DOM class, which has a perfectly good XPath query engine in it already.

```
[...snip...]
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc)
$images = $xpath->xpath('//img');
[...snip...]
```

Comment: I'm using xpath to simplify things here, I dont want to change all my code everywhere $xpath is later used that is working. I'm looking to find out why it stops @ the <body> tag

Answer (score -1):

The IMG tag is generated by javascript.
If you'd downloaded this page via wget, you'd realize there is no IMG tag in the HTML.

### Update #1

I believe it is because of user agent string.
If I supply "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 on x86_64; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0" as user agent id, I get the page in whole.

Comment: If I view the source of the page it looks like the gif mentioned in the post isnt generated by Javascript. Also, im not using wget

Comment: If I go to the page and hit view source, I get everything including images that dont appear to be generated by scripts. If I request it programmatically (which is what iwebtool is doing), the result is cut off @ the <body> tag - which is what I'm asking for an explanation for in my question here.