# Can't print_r domDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I only see:

`DOMNodeList Object ( )`

is this a php bug or something?

How am I supposed to see the HTML elements from the object?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but connected one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776093/why-var-dump-cant-print-domdocument-object-only-with-printdom-savehtml-its

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a DOMDocument instance, you have a PHP object. The DOM classes do not implement a helpful `__toString` functionality.

To get HTML from a DOMDocument instance, you'll need to use [`saveHTML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php):

```
print_r($dom->saveHTML());
```

NB that your question suggests you are actually looking at a collection of elements (a `DOMNodeList`) rather than an actual DOMDocument instance.  Depending on your code, you'll need to extract the code for these individually:

```
foreach ($elements as $el) {
    print_r($dom->saveHTML($el)); // use saveXML if you are using a version before 5.3.6
}
```

Comment: great.. are there any other classes like domdocument that work with print_r( ?

Comment: I can't believe that `print_r` is such a major part of your application that you have to choose what library you are using around it. Why do you need this?

Comment: well i cant see anything in the object, and I dont know what elements to remove and what not... I tried `$tag->parentNode->saveHTML()` and it doesnt work.. I get some fatal error. This has to be like the most stupid class ever. there's no remove element method etc.

Comment: That's because you need to call `saveHTML` on the DOMDocument instance, as I show in my code above.  You can use `$el->ownerDocument->saveHTML($el)` if you don't have a reference to it locally. It's not stupid, but the DOM can be a little tricky to get your head around. It's worth the work.