# XPath keeps returning empty node list

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

I am trying to parse a folder full of .htm files. All these files contain 1 specific element that needs to be removed.
It's a `td` element with `class="hide"`. So far, this is my code.
`$dir. entry` is the full path to the file.

```php
$page = ($dir . $entry);
$this->domDoc->loadHTMLFile($page);
// Use xpath query to find the menu and remove it
$nodeList = $xpath->query('//td[@class="hide"]');
```

Unfortunately, this is where things already go wrong. If I do a `var_dump` of the node list, I get the following:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#5 (0) { }
```

Just so you folks get an idea of what I'm trying to select, here's an excerpt:

```xml
<td width="160" align="left" valign="top" class="hide">
    lots of other TD's and content here
</td>
```

Does anybody see anything wrong with what I've come up with so far?

Comment: It would help us/you if you submitted some sample XML data.

Comment: Firefox provides Xpath addons which can be useful to double check your paths :)

Comment: Most of the DOM objects cannot be var_dumped, so this is expected.

Comment: @ZnArK: It's not actually XML, it's HTML I'm parsing. Still, I'll add it to clarify.

Comment: Is your initial file xhtml (i.e. with `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`)?  If so then your elements will be namespaced and you'll need to set up a prefix mapping using `$xpath->registerNamespace` and use this prefix in the expression e.g. `//xhtml:td`

Comment: @IanRoberts you're right. That solved it. Can't believe I spent so long trying to figure this out. Thank you.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776093/why-doesnt-var-dump-work-with-domdocument-objects-while-printdom-savehtml/4776430#4776430

Comment: @JensEeckhout I've turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your initial file xhtml (i.e. with `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`)? If so then your elements will be namespaced and you'll need to set up a prefix mapping using `$xpath->registerNamespace` and then use this prefix in the expression

```
$xpath->registerNamespace('xhtml', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');
$nodeList = $xpath->query('//xhtml:td[@class="hide"]');
```

Comment: this was the issue for me, I actually simply disabled the namespaces entirely while using this library https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php

Comment: Same for me (processing PHPUnit Coverage xml)
```php
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->load($coverageIndex);
$xml = new DOMXPath($xml);
$xml->registerNamespace('phpunit', 'https://schema.phpunit.de/coverage/1.0');
$items = $xml->query('//phpunit:build');
```

Answer (score 5):

Var dumping an xpath node list object doesn't show anything. Var dump the node list's length.

```
var_dump($nodeList->length);
```

If the value is over 0, then you can iterate over it using foreach:

```
foreach($nodeList as $node)var_dump($node->tagName);
```

Hope this helps.

For further clarification, here is a full working code snippet:

```
<?php
$html = <<<END
<html>
    <body>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td class="hide"></td>
        <td class="hide"></td>
    </body>
</html>
END;
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$nodeList = $xpath->query('//td[@class="hide"]');
// Shows a blank object
var_dump($nodeList);
// Shows 2
var_dump($nodeList->length);
// Echo out all the tag names.
foreach($nodeList as $node){
    echo $node->tagName . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right about the var_dump. I've changed that now. I've also checked my code -yet- again, and I see no difference compared to your snippet. Thank you for your reply though. Unfortunately I still get no output (the length of the nodelist returns `int(0)`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have more then one class in the `class` attribute of your `td` element:

```
<td class="hide anotherclass">
```

So `'//td[@class="hide"]'` would only match:

```
<td class="hide">
```

Try it like this to see if it contains the `hide` class you are looking for:

```
$nodeList = $xpath->query('//td[contains(@class,"hide")]');
```

Check out this blog post: [XPath: Select element by class](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/XPath%3A%20Select%20element%20by%20class.htm)

Comment: Good advice. I double-checked this, but "hide" really is the only class the TD has. Still, thank you, interesting reply.