# PHP using DOM to get anchors and modify them

Tags: php, dom, anchor

I have a string of HTML and I need check whether the href attributes of any anchors contain a certain link pattern. If they match a certain pattern I need to modify them.

Here's a sample HTML string:

```
<p>Disculpa, pero esta entrada está disponible sólo en <a href="http://www.example.com/static/?json=get_page&amp;post_type=page&amp;slug=sample-page&amp;lang=ru">Pусский</a> y <a href="http://www.example.com/static/?json=get_page&amp;post_type=page&amp;sample-page&amp;lang=en">English</a>.</p>
```

So the URLs in question take the following pattern

http://www.example.com/static/?json=get_page&post_type=page&slug=sample-page&lang=ru

Where the lang query attribute is variable in its value.

If a href matching that pattern is found I need to change it to:

http://www.example.com/ru/sample-page

So I need to remove 'static' and replace it with the value of the lang attribute, and I need to append the value of the 'slug' attribute to the end of the URL.

Sadly I'm getting confounded at the first step so I haven't even been able to test out methods of parsing the URLs and replacing them with the new value.

```
    $html = '<p>Disculpa, pero esta entrada está disponible sólo en <a href="http://www.example.com/static/?json=get_page&amp;post_type=page&amp;slug=sample-page&amp;lang=ru">Pусский</a> y <a href="http://www.example.com/static/?json=get_page&amp;post_type=page&amp;sample-page&amp;lang=en">English</a>.</p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
    // The UTF-8 encoding is necessary
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
```

In theory from this point on I'd loop through the anchors found and do stuff, but if I var_dump the $anchors variable I just get:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#66 (0) { }
```

So I can't even proceed further!

Any idea what's causing the DOM to fail to collect the anchors?

After that any suggestions on how to best identify if the anchor contains the URL pattern, change it and return the new modified HTML?

### Update 1

So it turns out that there's a PHP bug pre 5.4.1 which prevents var_dump from displaying the contents of the DOMNodeList. I can find values with

```
foreach ($anchors as $anchors) {
    echo $anchors->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

However I have no idea what the $anchors object really looks like so am running blind. If anyone has any suggestions on how to parse the $anchors and modify them as originally mentioned that would be hugely appreciated (whilst I try to sort out a PHP5.4.1 instance)

Comment: try doing `count($anchors)` see how much you get

Comment: Oddly, count($anchors) returns 1, but the var_dump is: object(DOMNodeList)#66 (0) { }

Comment: I've updated the question to show the $html variable and var_dump($anchors) instead of print_r

Comment: works fine at my end, i get `DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 2 )`. Did you check passing html without calling `mb_convert_encoding`. my guess is file encoding or data encoding is creating some problem for you.

Comment: That's super weird. I have absolutely no idea why it's not working. Hmm. I've dropped the encoding and still get var_dump($anchors) = object(DOMNodeList)#66 (0) { }

Comment: i get `DOMNodeList Object
(
    [length] => 2
)
`

Comment: whats the version of your PHP and DomDocument

Comment: Right, I've discovered the issue thanks to a friend's explanation. I can't var_dump the DOM object. I have to do foreach ($anchors as $anchors) {
    echo $anchors->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
} and then it gives values. Which is weird. I've tested this on our server running php5.2 and locally on xampp on php5.3.8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776093/why-doesnt-var-dump-work-with-domdocument-objects-while-printdom-savehtml - that's what was throwing me on that one...!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have done a similar thing not long ago. You can iterate over a DOMNodeList and then get the href attribute of the anchor.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    $original_url = $node->getAttribute('href');
    // Do something here
    $node->setAttribute('href', $var);
}
$html = $dom->saveHtml();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that after lunch :)

Comment: Hey Hayden! You totally set me on the right path :) I've updated your answer with the code that worked for me (I hope that's ok?) NB: http_build_url requires PECL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to echo the html first? Maybe you're passing an empty html or something.

Comment: I've just updated the question to show the HTML variable I'm passing to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this you will get the `href` value

```
$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
echo $anchors->item(0)->attributes->getNamedItem('href');
```

Comment: empty `$anchors` will not give anything!

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLinks($link)
{
$ret=array();

$dom=new DOMDocument;

@$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($link));

$dom->preserveWhiteSpace=false;

$links=$dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
 $html=$dom->saveHTML();
foreach($links as $tag)
{
    @$ret[$tag->getAttribute('href')]=$tag->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
}

return $ret;
}
$link="http://php.net";

 $url=getLinks($link);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with Hyden's answers. But I want to make the solution more independent. Because sometimes while we manipulate with DOM document, we face with encoding issues. Here is the advanced solution given below...........

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    $original_url = $node->getAttribute('href');
    // Do something here
    $node->setAttribute('href', $var);
}
$html = $dom->saveHtml();
```