# Why does PHP treats this DOM object like an array?

Tags: php, xml, domparser, php-7.3

I'm following this tutorial:

> https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_dom.asp

Looping through XML part is problematic.
PHP for some reason treats DOM object as an array. Furthermore, var_dump returns nothing about object attributes except length, but program output looks like it came out of nowhere. Can foreach loop through object somehow ? And if it does, where are these attributes contained (node name and node value) because var_dump is not showing them ?

```
$xml=new DOMDocument ();
$xml->load('note.xml');

$array_of_nodes=$xml->documentElement->childNodes;

var_dump($array_of_nodes);

foreach($array_of_nodes as $item) {
    echo $item->nodeName."  ".$item->nodeValue."<br>";
}
```

Var dump function returns this:

> object(DOMNodeList)#3 (1) { ["length"]=> int(9) } #text

But the executed code look like this:

> #### text =
>
> to = Tove
>
> #### text =
>
> from = Jani
>
> #### text =
>
> heading = Reminder
>
> #### text =
>
> body = Don't forget me this weekend!
>
> #### text =

Comment: That object is [Iterable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.iterable.php), just like an array is Iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`childNodes` is a property of `DOMNodeList` type. The reason why var_dump doesn't show anything about it is simply because var_dump shows only those class properties that have been declared by their developers by calling such C-functions as

```
ZEND_API int zend_declare_property(...)
ZEND_API int zend_declare_property_null(...)
ZEND_API int zend_declare_property_bool(...)
ZEND_API int zend_declare_property_long(...)
ZEND_API int zend_declare_property_double(...)
ZEND_API int zend_declare_property_string(...)
ZEND_API int zend_declare_property_stringl(...)
```

*Source: answer by akond: [Why doesn't var_dump work with DomDocument objects, while print($dom->saveHTML()) does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776093/why-doesnt-var-dump-work-with-domdocument-objects-while-printdom-savehtml)*

That is, developers of DOM extension chose not to expose the structure of `DOMNodeList` class.

The reason why you can iterate through `DOMNodeList` is because it implements `Traversable` interface which signals that the class can be iterated through by using `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

`DOMNodeList` implements several interfaces: `Traversable`, `ArrayAccess` and `Countable`. This allows using generic syntax to access the node objects in the list. Without them you would need to use specific methods and properties like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $c = $nodeList->length; $i < $c; $i++) {
  $node = $nodeList->item($i);
  //...
}
```

`Traversable` allows you to use `foreach`.

```
foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
  //...
}
```

`ArrayAccess` allows you use array syntax to access nodes by index, it replaces the `->item(...)` calls with `[...]`.

```
if (isset($nodeList[0])) {
  $node = $nodeList[0];
  //...
}
```

`Countable` allows you use `count($nodeList)` instead of `$nodeList->length`.

`Traversable` has the most visual impact. It greatly reduces the complexity of the call. But that is only the first benefit. You can validate against the interfaces using typehints or `instanceof`. This decouples you code, making it more robust and reusable.

However looping trough DOM is a lot easier if you use Xpath expressions. If you used CSS selectors before, you can think of Xpath expressions as a more powerful sibling.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load('note.xml');
$xpath = DOMXpath($document);

foreach($xpath->evaluate('/note') as $item) {
    echo 'To: ', $xpath->evaluate('string(to)', $item), "\n";
    echo 'From: ', $xpath->evaluate('string(from)', $item), "\n";
    echo 'Title: ', $xpath->evaluate('string(heading)', $item), "\n";
    echo 'Text: ', $xpath->evaluate('string(body)', $item), "\n";
}
```