# PHP: XML Parsing with probably invalid content

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I need a template-engine for a project, that parses sgml-content and converts user-defined tags like `<ext:grid />`. In nearly every case, the input-content is valid. A common problem is the link-generator. The link-generator produces `&` instead of `&amp;` which is the main cause of my parsing-problems. I cant change this behavior, because the output of that generator is used in many other situations where the links are required to have an `&` instead of `&amp;`.

I have tried DOMDocument, SimpleXML and xml_parser. They all exit on entity problems. Any ideas? All I want is, that this "problem" gets simply ignored by the parser.

Where is a test-template:

```
<template xmlns:grid="templates/grid" xmlns:std="templates/std">
    <std:header text="Overview" type="h1" />
    <grid:base width="100%">
        <grid:columns>
        <grid:body>
            <?php foreach($products as $product): /* @var $product Dfm_Shop_Model_Product */ ?>
            <grid:row selectable="1">
                <grid:cell>
                    <div><?php echo $this->esc($product->getTitle()) ?></div>
                </grid:cell>
                <grid:cell>
                    <a href="<?php env()->http()->to(array('controller' => 'Dfm_Shop_Controller_Products', 'method' => 'showEdit')) ?>"><std:img src="icons/pencil.png" hint="Edit" /></a>
                </grid:cell>
            </grid:row>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </grid:body>
    </grid:base>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just search-replace your `&` to `&amp;` before trying to parse the document?

---

Edit: Just to add for the completeness, there's for example [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) that [can handle invalid tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987239/querypath-and-malformed-html), too.

According to the thread linked above, libxml functions should've also worked.

Comment: preg_replace would consume too much performance. A simple str_replace would replace `&amp;` with `&amp;amp;`. I should try strtr for this...

Comment: you can first str_replace `&amp;` to `&`, and then replace back :) that would of course fail with any other proper xml entities, like `&apos;` ...

Comment: `$content = strtr($content, array('&amp;' => '&amp;', '&' => '&amp;'));` does the trick

Comment: `This problem is actually that your XML is not XML at all, but something close to it`. The content is virtually correct xml. Now DOMDocument can parse the document without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, try to use cdata with xml.

```
<![CDATA[your content]]>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: That would require me to all CDATA everywhere I used my link-generator. That would be the same if I would just use htmlentities around the link-generator. Too easy to forget :/

Comment: But it can solve your problem permanently. To build a good system we need to do some extra efforts.